# Integrating Floor Functions

Tags: calculus, integration, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I am having difficulties understanding and solving the following problem.

[image: Problem]

So far I think I understand the first line. I know what the graph of floor[t] looks like and I understand they're asking to integrate from 0 to some value of n and that integral always equals the equation on the right. I do not really understand what they are asking for in the second line or how that differs from the first equation.

I have checked through my notes and various online sources and we've just covered the fundamental theorem of calculus and discussed integration using partitions on an interval to calculate area but I am also unsure about how to relate these to this problem if they are even needed.

Any pointers, explanations or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

What they want you to do is extend the same function beyond an integer domain, so 
if $k = \lfloor x \rfloor $
$$\int_0^x\lfloor t\rfloor\ dt = \int_0^k\lfloor t\rfloor\ dt +\int_k^x\lfloor t\rfloor\ dt=\frac{(k-1)(k)}{2} + \cdots$$

---

EDIT:
Let's take a closer look at $\int_k^x \lfloor t \rfloor \ dt$.
Recall that $k = \lfloor x \rfloor$, and since this is the closest integer value less than $x$, we know a few things.

1. $k < x < k+1$
2. $x - k < 1$

Because of this, we know that if $t$ between $k$ and $x$, $\lfloor t\rfloor = k$, for all $t$ in that interval.
Because of this, we are integrating a constant between $k$ and $x$, so the area of that region would be a rectangle with length $(x-k)$ and height $k$.

Comment: Thank you that makes sense. Does that mean that the the integral from 0 to k and then k to x is the formula you have written added to the the first formula they have provided?

Comment: @Michael the formula I wrote on the right hand side is the one they provided (they are the same since $k=\lfloor x\rfloor$), I left it to you to think about what the missing piece would be.
A secondary hint would be that since $k=\lfloor x\rfloor$, $x < k+1$, so what values would $\lfloor t \rfloor$ take for $t\in (k,x)$?

Comment: Ok thank you. I just wasn't sure so I thought I would ask.

Comment: @Michael, no worries. Hope that helps

Comment: Sorry can I ask another question please. Why isn't the integral of 0 to k the same as k to x? I still do not really understand how you would prove their integral and then the next step.

Comment: @Michael, I've added a few more details into the answer

Comment: That helps thank you but I'm still not sure. I'll have to try and get a copy of the solutions. Sorry its not what you've written, I'm just not getting the question.